# Cannot create database as root in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, vps

I just got my VPS. I log in to phpMyAdmin as the root but I cannot create a database. I can't even see a link for this. I also want to change other user's permissions, but I cannot find out how to do this.

Comment: can you explain more! can you go to database tab in phpmyadmin ? if so do you see input box with label  create new databases?

Comment: i am logging in phpmyadmin from cpanel VHM and in phpmyadmin when i go to database tab there is no input box and also there is no input box on index page too.